# Issue with Inserting new rows at bottom of table and deleting top row

Tags: excel, vba

My file looks like the attached. The following snippet is attempting to insert rows only on the worksheets I have not specified. This will begin at cell B3 and work its way down. So it inserts a row at B34 as this is the first new row and will delete row B3 so the range will continue exponentially.

I believe the code very nearly does this. I need to complete the aforementioned but then also copy the formula shown in cell B4 to B5 as a formula and then paste b4 as values. this is so that when another macro is run which updates the workbook, only the value with the formula will change and not the prior weeks. I have charts looking at this range, so each time a different macro is run the latest value will show and a new value will show in the range and the subsequent charts. Hope this makes sense! [image] [image]

```
Sub INSERT_NEW_ROWS()
Dim rs As Worksheet
For Each rs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If rs.name <> "3110" And rs.name <> "Data" And rs.name <> "Wholesale" And rs.name <> "Retail" And rs.name <> "Pivot 1" And rs.name <> "Pivot 2" And rs.name <> "Pivot 3" And rs.name <> "Pivot 4" And rs.name <> "Pivot 5" And rs.name <> "Pivot 6" And rs.name <> "Pivot 7" And rs.name <> "Pivot 8" And rs.name <> "Pivot 9" And rs.name <> "Pivot 10" And rs.name <> "Pivot 11" Then
   rs.name = rs.Range("B3:B").Value 
Next rs
End
  ' Go to last cell
  Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
  ' Copy formula from cell above
  Rows(Selection.Row - 1).Copy
  Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
      Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

     ws.Range("2:2").Delete
     Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks a lot like rolling period charts I use. If the values are formula derived (or could be via lookups) I would maintain a master table with all data in and simply have a formula in your chart table that finds the max date from the master table and uses that as the last date in your rolling period in the date column. Then all the rows above that are just -1 from the row above. Then it self updates as you add data with no need to add/remove rows.

Comment: That's a good idea ……..I have 42 different data items, plus a rolling 30 days so 1260 possible data items with formulas. Considering people here use laptops, it will probably fall over and die hence why i'm trying the macro route. If there wasn't so many data items I would agree with you mate :) thanks for replying!

Comment: Put your data in an Access/sql database and then write a query to pull only the latest rolling period months into your workbook. Or better still generate the final output in the database and output only what you need in the format you need.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
Sub INSERT_NEW_ROWS()
Dim rs As Worksheet
For Each rs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If rs.Name <> "3110" And rs.Name <> "Data" And rs.Name <> "Wholesale" And rs.Name 
<> "Retail" And rs.Name <> "Pivot 1" And rs.Name <> "Pivot 2" And rs.Name <> "Pivot 
3" And rs.Name <> "Pivot 4" And rs.Name <> "Pivot 5" And rs.Name <> "Pivot 6" And 
rs.Name <> "Pivot 7" And rs.Name <> "Pivot 8" And rs.Name <> "Pivot 9" And rs.Name <> 
"Pivot 10" And rs.Name <> "Pivot 11" Then

' LastRow in column A
LastRowa = rs.Cells(rs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' LastRow in column B
LastRowb = rs.Cells(rs.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row    

'Copy paste the last row, based on what's in column A in the next empty row

rs.Cells(LastRowa, 2).EntireRow.Copy
rs.Cells(LastRowa + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

'Change the formula of the last cell in column  B into a value
rs.Cells(LastRowb, 2).Copy
rs.Cells(LastRowb + 1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
rs.Cells(LastRowb, 2).Value = rs.Cells(LastRowb, 2).Value
End If
Next rs

End Sub
```

Comment: THanks Lambik, partially working now thanks very much! I just need it copy the entire row so all data tables have a new row now, not just column B please?

Comment: Lambik thank you very much my friend, greatly appreciated! There is only one thing left that I need to do, which is copy the formula down where it is located in one of the columns, in this case B3 to B4 as a formula, then paste the cell above as a value. Is this something I could incorporate into the above or run as a separate sub routine? Thanks!!!

Comment: I was under the impression that that is done. What happens is, the LastRow is copy-pasted (formulas) to the first new blank row. Subsequently using the ´rs.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = rs.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value´ , the formula in Row B of the LastRow is replaced by its value. If it isn't, please elaborate on what's happening now, my test worked as expected

Comment: Hey Lambik, thanks for your response. It is incrementing the very bottom row which is perfect, I just now need to take the formula where it exists, in this case cell b3 and copy this to the next row below, which will be B4. I will then need to paste the above row (B3) which will then become a value whilst B4 will now have the formula. When you next do this the B5 will now have the formula and the B4 will be pasted as values. Sorry for the confusion mate

Comment: Please check if this is what you meant, I'm a bit confused, but I think this is what you want to obtain. If not, check what the code does and explain clearly what it not working correctly. If it is the correct answer, please flag my answer as such, thanks,

Comment: Hi Lambik. Unfortunately, it's not moving the formula down to the next row or even as a value, so I am unable to see if this is working or not. Data stays on the 03 November Line and does not move to the 4th November as expected. Thanks for trying mate

Comment: changed the code a little bit to correct for a copy-paste error. If it doesn't work, I really would need to see the workbook and exact coding you use, as it works on my testfile...

Comment: Lambik I really appreciate you looking at this for me my friend, but it isn't looking for the last value in a column, copying this down as a formula then pasting the above row as a value. I have stored the above macro in my workbook, if you would be so kind to email acrasherkid@googlemail.com I can send you it? Thanks for the help :)